# Disable selected option from one select box when selected in another select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got 2 location select boxes and 2 color boxes. I wrote a jQuery code to disable a location option if it is selected from either of the location select boxes in the other.

The code I wrote it working for the location boxes but for some reason after the initial selection of an option in either of the location select boxes, the options from color boxes are also getting disabled.

This only happens when I try to select an option from a location select box second time

here is my full code. What I am doing wrong. Thanks

```
<div class="pc-row">
    <div class="locations-colors pc-col quote-sizes">
      <h4>Choose location below</h4>
       <label for="location_one"><span>Location</span>
        <select name="location_one" id="location_one">
         <option value="">choose location</option>
         <option value="Full_Chest">Full Chest</option>
         <option value="Full_Back">Full Back</option>
         <option value="Front_Left_Chest">Front Left Chest</option>
         <option value="Front_Right_Chest">Front Right Chest</option>
         <option value="Left_Sleeve">Left Sleeve</option>
         <option value="Right_Sleeve">Right Sleeve</option>      
        </select></label>

    </div>
    <div class="locations-colors pc-col quote-sizes">
      <h4>Choose number of colors for location</h4>
       <label for="color_one"><span>Number of Colors</span>
        <select name="color_one" id="color_one">
         <option value="">choose colors</option>
         <option value="0">One Color</option>
         <option value="1">Two Colors</option>
         <option value="2">Three Colors</option>
         <option value="3">Four Colors</option>
        </select></label>

    </div>
    </div>

        <div class="pc-row">
    <div class="locations-colors pc-col quote-sizes">
       <label for="location_two"><span>Location</span>
        <select name="location_two" id="location_two">
         <option value="">choose location</option>
         <option value="Full_Chest">Full Chest</option>
         <option value="Full_Back">Full Back</option>
         <option value="Front_Left_Chest">Front Left Chest</option>
         <option value="Front_Right_Chest">Front Right Chest</option>
         <option value="Left_Sleeve">Left Sleeve</option>
         <option value="Right_Sleeve">Right Sleeve</option>          
        </select></label>

    </div>
    <div class="locations-colors pc-col quote-sizes">
       <label for="color_two"><span>Number of Colors</span>
        <select name="color_two" id="color_two">
         <option value="">choose colors</option>
         <option value="1">One Color</option>
         <option value="2">Two Colors</option>
         <option value="3">Three Colors</option>
         <option value="4">Four Colors</option>
        </select></label>

    </div>
    </div>
```

and the JavaScript

```
    $('select[name*="location"]').change(function() {
    var selectedOptions = $('select option:selected');
    $('select option').removeAttr('disabled');
    selectedOptions.each(function() {        
        var value = this.value;
        if (value !== ''){           
        var id = $(this).parent('select[name*="location"]').attr('id');
        var options = $('select:not(#' + id + ') option[value=' + value + ']');
        options.attr('disabled', 'true');
        }
    });
});
```

```js
 $('select[name*="location"]').change(function() {
    var selectedOptions = $('select option:selected');
    $('select option').removeAttr('disabled');
    selectedOptions.each(function() {        
        var value = this.value;
        if (value !== ''){           
        var id = $(this).parent('select[name*="location"]').attr('id');
        var options = $('select:not(#' + id + ') option[value=' + value + ']');
        options.attr('disabled', 'true');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.adult-sizes-box{margin:10px 0}#totalprice{display:none}
.quote-sizes li{margin:5px 0 10px}input.amtbox{width:100px;border:1px solid #ccc;vertical-align:middle;float:left}.quote-sizes select{border:1px solid #ccc;font-size:14px}
.quote-sizes label {cursor:inherit;display:block;width:100%;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap}.quote-sizes label span{font-size:14px;text-align:right;float:left;margin-right:3px;vertical-align:middle;width:120px}
.section-title{background:#ddd;padding:10px;font-size:18px}.small-title{font-size:24px;color:#990000}
.pc-row {width: 100%; display: table; table-layout: fixed; }.pc-col {display:table-cell;vertical-align:top}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pc-row">
 <div class="locations-colors pc-col quote-sizes">
   <h4>Choose location below</h4>
    <label for="location_one"><span>Location</span>
     <select name="location_one" id="location_one">
         <option value="">choose location</option>
   <option value="Full_Chest">Full Chest</option>
   <option value="Full_Back">Full Back</option>
         <option value="Front_Left_Chest">Front Left Chest</option>
         <option value="Front_Right_Chest">Front Right Chest</option>
         <option value="Left_Sleeve">Left Sleeve</option>
   <option value="Right_Sleeve">Right Sleeve</option>   
        </select></label>
  
 </div>
 <div class="locations-colors pc-col quote-sizes">
   <h4>Choose number of colors for location</h4>
    <label for="color_one"><span>Number of Colors</span>
     <select name="color_one" id="color_one">
         <option value="">choose colors</option>
   <option value="0">One Color</option>
   <option value="1">Two Colors</option>
         <option value="2">Three Colors</option>
         <option value="3">Four Colors</option>
        </select></label>
  
 </div>
 </div>
 
  <div class="pc-row">
 <div class="locations-colors pc-col quote-sizes">
    <label for="location_two"><span>Location</span>
     <select name="location_two" id="location_two">
         <option value="">choose location</option>
   <option value="Full_Chest">Full Chest</option>
   <option value="Full_Back">Full Back</option>
         <option value="Front_Left_Chest">Front Left Chest</option>
         <option value="Front_Right_Chest">Front Right Chest</option>
         <option value="Left_Sleeve">Left Sleeve</option>
   <option value="Right_Sleeve">Right Sleeve</option>    
        </select></label>
  
 </div>
 <div class="locations-colors pc-col quote-sizes">
    <label for="color_two"><span>Number of Colors</span>
     <select name="color_two" id="color_two">
         <option value="">choose colors</option>
   <option value="1">One Color</option>
   <option value="2">Two Colors</option>
         <option value="3">Three Colors</option>
         <option value="4">Four Colors</option>
        </select></label>
  
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your js, `var options = $('select:not(#' + id + ') option[value=' + value + ']');` is the pb, you reinit the var to match any select option and not only the one for location.

So just replace with `var options = $('select[name*="location"]:not(#' + id + ') option[value=' + value + ']');`

Answer (score 0):

Why are the same two events? whether should be adjusted following code

```
$('select[name*="location"]').change(function() {
....
});

$('select[name*="color"]').change(function() {
....
});
```